# How to add new line in alert box ng-bootstrap

Tags: ng-bootstrap

I am trying to add new line in alert box.
I tried appending "\n" "< br >" and "< ul > < li >"
but still no luck
Can you please advise
I am using angular 6 and ng-bootstrap 3.x.x

### alert-basic.ts

import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'ngbd-alert-basic',

templateUrl: './alert-basic.html'

})

export class NgbdAlertBasic {

alertType = "danger";

alertMessage="< ul > < li > Why this is happening with me?< /li >< li > Can you solve the puzzle Pleazze < /li >< /ul > ";

}

### alert-basic.html

< ngb-alert *ngIf="alertMessage" type="{{alertType}}" (close)="alertMessage = null">{{ alertMessage }}< /ngb-alert>

Answer (score 0):

Usage of @ng-bootstrap alert:
https://stackblitz.com/angular/vkgxbmgdglnx

Works for me

Comment: I am unsing @ng-bootstrap alert component

Comment: Have a look at the Stackblitz. I used `<br`, `<ul><li></li></ul>` and `<p>`

Comment: Thank you sir updated question with my problem ts and html. I tried to run this in stack blitz no luck